# How to place labels on multi-geometries in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, qgis-2.6, multi-geometry

I need to put a label value on each geometry, so I do not need to locate the label on the  (or near to) centroid.

I use QGIS 2.6 on windows 7

Most ot the records has only one geometry linked to, but I have some records with more geometry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an option ate the Layer Labeling Settings > Rendering > Feature options > "Label every part of multi-part features"

[image]

Just check that option.